# JSF 2.2 faces-config: Unknown Schema version: 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to use the Faces 2.2. I get an error.

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'jndi:/server/contracts/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': Unknown Schema version: 2.2
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:749)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:348)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4750)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5366)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'jndi:/server/contracts/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': Unknown Schema version: 2.2
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:747)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to parse document 'jndi:/server/contracts/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml': Unknown Schema version: 2.2
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:998)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:942)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:735)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Unknown Schema version: 2.2
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.getDocument(ConfigManager.java:1101)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$ParseTask.call(ConfigManager.java:989)
    ... 48 more
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>

        <resource-library-contracts>
            <contract-mapping>
                <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
                <contracts>blue</contracts>
            </contract-mapping>
            <contract-mapping>
                <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
                <contracts>red</contracts>
            </contract-mapping>
        </resource-library-contracts>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

The code of this [example.](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/resource_library_contracts_in_jsf2)

I copied latest JSF version  over "glassfish3/glassfish/modules/javax.faces.jar" file.

I do not understand the problem.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The schema namespace for JSF 2.2 changed. The `faces-config.xml` has to look like this:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

</faces-config>
```

Comment: Is there an official place where I can look this stuff up? I don't want future me to have to crawl the web when the namespace changes again.

Comment: Is this really correct? At first seemed to me there was a typo there if you compare it with other replies: the value for xsi:schemaLocation seems wrong, as the first "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" part seems duplicated. But then if I remove it, my IDE throws an alert stating that "schemaLocation value = 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd' must have even number of URI's.". Which one is the right value?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with eclipse. I still get a warning ("No grammar costraints..)
But the application works. 
this is my faces-config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <faces-config
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">


    <application>
            <action-listener>org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener</action-    listener>
            <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
            <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>

        <locale-config>
             <default-locale>de</default-locale>
             <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>Messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

Messages is the base file names for the properties.The files are called Messages.properties (default) and Messages_de.properties.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this problem is that http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd address is invalid. Therefore, I can advise you to use following `faces-config.xml` file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

    <faces-config version="2.2"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
       <application>

            <resource-library-contracts>
                <contract-mapping>
                    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
                    <contracts>blue</contracts>
                </contract-mapping>
                <contract-mapping>
                    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
                    <contracts>red</contracts>
                </contract-mapping>
            </resource-library-contracts>
        </application>

    </faces-config>
```

Comment: Only the above URL (http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd) works. The one from Oracle provided here correctly downloads but is not capable of validating an empty faces-config.xml.