# "URI is not registered" of default xmlns in faces-config and MyFaces 2.2

Tags: intellij-idea, jsf-2.2, xml-namespaces, myfaces, faces-config

I am in the process of updating the JSF implementation of our project from JSF 1.1 to JSF 2.2. I mainly use [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0) as a guide.

When updating the root element of the `faces-config.xml` according to [JSF 2.2 faces-config: Unknown Schema version: 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124684/jsf-2-2-faces-config-unknown-schema-version-2-2) to

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
```

my IDE - IntelliJ - marks the default XML namespace `xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"` red and when hovering over it gives me the error message:

```
URI is not registered
```

[image]

`http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd` also gets marked as erroneous, showing the following error message when hovering over it:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd'
```

[image]

I use `MyFaces 2.2.12` as JSF implementation and `IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.1` as IDE. (I am aware that the CE of IntelliJ does not feature the same level of JSF support as the Ultimate Edition, but this is not really a JSF problem, but rather a XML problem, isn't it?)

Can anyone tell me what I need to change to make IntelliJ recognize the xmlns-URI?

**Edit:**

I tried to "Manually setup external resource" like described in [JSF xmlns URI not registered in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410936/jsf-xmlns-uri-not-registered-in-intellij-idea), but if I do this for `web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd`, every element in `faces-config.xml` gets marked with an error. When I hover over the marked elements I get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: MyFaces 2.2.what? 2.2.0? 2.2.666?

Comment: It's MyFaces 2.2.12 (edited in question)

Comment: I get a similar namespace URI error for the `tomahawk` and `htmLib` tag libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477393/how-to-use-taglibrary-htmlib-from-jsftutorials-net-with-jsf2-2 Could this be related?